# How do I save the directory from popd to a variable without changing the directory?

Tags: bash, macos, cd

I know I've run into this problem on my Linux box, but right now I'm on Mac OS X and I need to do the same thing. I want to use pushd and popd to call scripts or binaries in several locations, but I need to keep the same working directory during this time.

This is a test script. I think this is the dumb way I did this beforehand:

```
cd ~
pushd . 1>/dev/null
cd Documents
NEW_DIR=`pwd`
OLD_DIR=$(`popd`)
cd $OLD_DIR
echo Current directory: `pwd`
echo New directory: $NEW_DIR
```

Which results in:

```
$ ./pushpop.sh
./pushpop.sh: line 5: cd: ~: No such file or directory
Current directory: /Users/NobleUplift
New directory: /Users/NobleUplift/Documents
```

It works, but not without an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popd` is a command which will pop the top of the directory stack and change your working directory to it, so you don't need to use `cd`. Hence your `pushpop.sh` should read like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/
pushd . 1>/dev/null
cd Documents
NEW_DIR=`pwd`
popd
echo Current directory: `pwd`
echo New directory: $NEW_DIR
```

And you'll get output as you desire:

```
~
Current directory: /home/imp25
New directory: /home/imp25/Documents
```

#### Edit following OPs comments

If you want to capture the output of `popd` without moving directory, it's probably best to interograte the directory stack which `pushd` adds to and `popd` pops off. You can view the stack with the [command `dirs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html), which will give a list of directories, the first being your current working directory, i.e.:

```
cd ~
pushd .
cd Documents
pushd .
dirs
~/Documents ~/Documents ~
```

You can access specific entries in the stack with the `+N` and `-N` options to dirs (`+N` starts counting from the left, `-N` starts counting from the right). If you want to get the last thing you pushed to the stack it can be accessed with `dirs +1`.

Modifying your script would give you something like:

```
cd ~/
pushd . 1>/dev/null
cd Documents
NEW_DIR=`pwd`
OLD_DIR=$(dirs -l +1)
cd $OLD_DIR
echo Current directory: `pwd`
echo New directory: $NEW_DIR
```

Here `$(dirs -l +1)` gets the top of the stack you pushed and returns it in long form (expanding `~` to `/home/foo` for example). I think the error you're getting is around `cd` not handling `~` as a directory properly, hence the use of the `-l` option.

Comment: I missed the very last phrase in the manual that says as much :P. My friend introduced pushd/popd to me and this is how he wrote it. I guess we've both been doing it wrong all this time.

Comment: Is it possible to popd into a variable? That's what I actually needed but I phrased my question quite poorly.

Comment: @NobleUplift I've updated the answer to reflect the changes to the question and your comments.

Comment: Thanks! It really helped be out having this before the end of the day.